# How can I recover 2 LUKS2 partitions formatted by mistake?

Tags: format, partition-recovery, luks, recovery

I wanted to install a new Linux distro so I deleted the previous partitions used for Fedora install at the beginning of the disk ~120 Gb and I had the rest of the 2/3 of the disk compose out of 2 LUKS2 partitions since Fedora 36 or 37.

Unfortunately the automatic partitioning of the new distro setup decided to format my whole drive instead of using the empty space. I have stopped the setup as soon as I've seen what is doing.

I have tried the steps taken by other people here with:

```
sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda  | grep LUKS
```

And I've got a 6700 lines long output (I can share it if you tell me how can I do it without flooding this site)

I've tried with some of the offsets from the output:

```
sudo losetup -o 0x......... -r -f /dev/sda
losetup -a
and they seem to work but  
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/loop0 luksrecover 
gives me an error output  
Device /dev/sda is not a valid LUKS device.
```

Can someone help me please ?

---

TestDisk does not identify partitions that have the start after ~120 Gb as I would expect.

```
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility

Disk /dev/nvme0n1 - 512 GB / 476 GiB - CHS 488386 64 32
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P FAT32                    0   1  3   476  53  2     976512 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME]
 P FAT32                    0   1  9   476  53  8     976512 [NO NAME]
 P NTFS                     1   0  1 488386  20 15 1000213135
 P ext4                   489   0  1 106915  63 32  217962496
 P ext4                   490   0  1 116452   0 32  237490208 [Linux]
 P ext4                   602   0  1  1625  63 32    2097152
 P ext4                   667  63 31 488385  63 30  998846464
>P ext4                   668   0  1 488385  63 32  998846464
 P ext4                 11163  63 31 12827  63 30    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 11164   0  1 12827  63 32    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 11259  63 31 11734  49 14     972336 [vendor]
 P ext4                 11260   0  1 11734  49 16     972336 [vendor]
 P ext4                 11675  63 31 13339  63 30    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 11676   0  1 13339  63 32    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 11771  63 31 12246  49 14     972336 [vendor]
 P ext4                 11772   0  1 12246  49 16     972336 [vendor]
 P ext4                 12187  63 31 13851  63 30    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 12188   0  1 13851  63 32    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 13075  63 31 14739  63 30    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 13076   0  1 14739  63 32    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 13587  63 31 15251  63 30    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 13588   0  1 15251  63 32    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 13844   0  1 15507  63 32    3407872 [/]
 P ext4                 15716   0  1 16190  49 16     972336 [vendor]
Structure: Ok.


Keys T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 511 GB / 476 GiB
```

Comment: Have you no disk image made before that change??

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Unless you have a partition or disk level backup somewhere (or a copy of the LUKS header) you are out of luck.

LUKS has a header which contains the ultimately used encryption key - without it the data cant be decrypted.

If you have overwritten that header (which appears the case) any recovery requires that header be made available - practically restored to the LUKS block before data can be decrypted.

Comment: From what I have read the header is at the beginning of every LUKS encrypted partition which in my case is after the first 120 Gb of the disk. The formatting was done in the first few Mb on the disk and using the sudo hexdump -C /dev/sda  | grep LUKS    I got over 6800 mentions of the word LUKS on my disk. I`m pretty sure all the data and the headers are still there, I just need someone smarter than me to help me with the CLI commands to make it readable again.

Comment: In that case, have you tried using testdisk to scan the disk and try and find the old partitions?  LUKS would be typically be on a partition (eg /dev/sdaX) rather then a disk (/dev/sda).  [ If you were using LVM it could also be further abstracted )

Comment: I tried testdisk but it doesn`t find them because of the LVM I think, it finds the small FAT32 partition at the begining of the disk and a partition as big as the whole disk after it.

Comment: Its a longshot, but if the data is psrticularly valuable I would bitcopy the entire disk, then - on the copy let testdisk write those partition tables and then try further operations on the second partition - starting by identifying if the header of the second partitiom is a PV (physical volume) for LVM.